# return 500 error using WordprocessingDocument in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

hello i using WordprocessingDocument for read text of word files but after send file WordprocessingDocument return 500 error for me
controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {

            string path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", "uploadFiles");
            using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {

                 file.CopyTo(fs);

                var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName), FileMode.Open);
                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

                    Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
                    return new JsonResult(body);
                }
            }


        }
```

befor word proccer using code work correctly after wordproccer code continue without error but  get 500 error response

[image]

Comment: We need to know what's the details error message from your web api. I suggest you could use network tab and select the right path to see what's the details error message or please use visual studio debug model to see the details error message.

Comment: I do not receive any error and it will be ignored when it reaches this code